# How to apply CSS to my JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a JQuery component plugin that requires some minimal default css. (The css is required for the component's functional layout- not just style dressing)  Should I:

- Write a separate .css file and dynamically load it in my plugin code (How would I do this?)
- Apply the css attributes directly in my plugin code using JQuery's .css(...)

It seems the second option would be a more secure way of ensuring my component gets the css it needs.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm a fan of keeping CSS in a separate file and then importing it using the plugin.

Overtime, this makes it easier to maintain and it makes it easier for users or future developers to work with your plugin rather than digging through JavaScript source (which will likely grow overtime).

To apply a stylesheet with jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(function() {
  $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin-styles.css" type="text/css" />');
});
```

Obviously, you'll need to know the path to the CSS file but If you ship a `css` directory with your plugin, this shouldn't be problem.

As far as "ensuring [your] component gets the css it needs," the first option will work file as long as you make sure your elements have a unique identifier (classname or ID) that the JavaScript source can access.

If you want to make sure that you're not loading the stylesheet multiple times, you can do something like this:

```
$(function() {

  var bStylesheetExists = false;
  $('link').each(function() { 
    if($(this).attr('href') === 'plugin-style.css')) {
       bStylesheetExists = true;
    }
  });

  if(bStylesheetExists === false) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin-styles.css" type="text/css" />');
  }

});
```

Comment: @Tom- thanks a lot, seems like a good method- But how would you ensure that this was only being called once per page?  If I put this in the init method of a plugin I use multiple times on a page, I'd get multiple link tags...

Comment: @Yarin - personally, I wouldn't load the CSS in the jQuery, just keep a separate CSS file.  That way whoever's using your plugin can include the .js and .css from wherever they are in their directory structure, without needing to edit your plugin.

Comment: @Yarin - There are a couple of options to verify that the stylesheet is loaded, but you could always examine the existing link elements checking their href properties. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with Tom about keeping them separate. However, if you did want to go with styling the plugin in the jQuery code, then here's a great tutorial on how to set defaults and expose them as configurable properties: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/06/glowbuttons_writing_my_first_j.html

Answer (score 1):

Like @Tom idea, although I've seen plenty of jquery plugins with a separate CSS file.

But I'm inclined to suggest that a separate CSS file is involved so that:

- styles can be overridden by the user if necessary
- name clashes can be debugged
- the cascade is predictable

I've used a couple of jquery plugins that inexcusably defined styles for tag elements (not classes, not ids but the actual blummin' tags); so if you do 'hide' the styles, please use classes with a prefix/suffix related to your plugin to avoid clashes.